# Why is Java not printing all the words in the line (when words are added to an ArrayList)?

Tags: java, arraylist, println

When printing out the user input as indvidual words within a line I get a printout of all the words in that line.

```
System.out.println(userInput.next());
```

However, when I add the indvidual words to an ArrayList I appear to be getting random words back:

```
 al.add(userInput.next());
```

Could someone explain to me what's going on?

Thanks.

This is a full copy of the code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Kwic {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();


        while(userInput.hasNext()){
            al.add(userInput.next());
            System.out.println(userInput.next());
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) consumes the *next* token from the scanner. Thus, when you have:

```
        al.add(userInput.next());
        System.out.println(userInput.next());
```

You are actually consuming *two* tokens from the scanner. The first is being added to the `ArrayList` and the *other* is being printed to `System.out`. A possible solution is to store the token in a local variable, and then add it to the array and print it:

```
    while (userInput.hasNext()) {
        String token = userInput.next();
        al.add(token);
        System.out.println(token);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

```
while(userInput.hasNext()){
    al.add(userInput.next());   //Adding userInput call to ArrayList
    System.out.println(userInput.next());  //Printing another userInput call
}
```

You are **not** printing the value stored in your ArrayList but actually another call to the userInput.next()

**Revision**

@**Sheldon** This is working for me.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(userInput.hasNext()){
        al.add(userInput.next());
        System.out.println(al);  //LINE CHANGED FROM YOUR QUESTION
    }

}
```

I tested your code with input
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`

Then I pressed enter and Got:

`2
4
6
8
0`

the userInput.next() is alternating between the one added to the ArrayList and the one captured by your System.out.println

Comment: I don't think I explained myself well enough. When I use System.out.println(userInput.next()); I'm not getting all the words in the line e.g. "How are you" is not printing "How" "Are" "You" but instead just printing "are". This only happens when I'm adding the values to the ArrayList though.

Comment: @Sheldon If I print the arrayList instead of userInput.next() it still works.

Comment: @Sheldon I got it now... it's your while loop first entry goes to the list, second entry goes to your System.println

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it this way:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Kwic {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();


        while(userInput.hasNext()){
                al.add(userInput.next());
        }
    System.out.println(al);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more beneficial for you to store all of the values into the `ArrayList` first, *then* print them out.  What you're doing now is printing another call to `userInput.next()`, which may or may not be present.

```
while(userInput.hasNext()){
    al.add(userInput.next());
}

for(String s : al) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
al.add(userInput.next());   //Adding an Item call to ArrayList

System.out.println(userInput.next()); //Printing the next userInput with a call**
```

**Try this to print the values in ArrayList**

```
for(String s : al){

     System.out.println(s);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only  you're not printing all the words in the line, you're also not adding all the words into the `ArrayList`. Because the way you have coded, it adds every alternate words to the `ArrayList` and prints the alternate words.